# Remote Tomcat installation Powershell script issue

Tags: powershell

I am a powershell newbie attempting to write a script for a remote installation.  I had it all working for local install but found I needed to make several changes for it to work on a remote install.  I have most of the necessary configuration figured out but my issue is that the cmd.exe command I was using for local installation doesn't work for a remote installation.  I am trying to figure out the equivalent Start-Process command.  The Start-Process I have below doesn't give an error but also doesn't work as expected.  So what is the equivalent Start-Process command for this cmd.exe command?

This works for local installation but not remote installation:

```
Set-Location $destination\bin
cmd.exe /c "service.bat install tomcat9"
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. No errors or installation.

```
Start-Process -filepath "$destination\bin\service.bat" -ArgumentList "install tomcat9 /Setup /install /norestart" -Wait -NoNewWindow -passthru
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me.

& "$using:destination\bin\service.bat" install tomcat9